# Javascript is not loading in Zen custom theme

Tags: theming

I'm not able to get my custom theme to run javascript on all pages. My code is as follows. My Custom module is enabled, and Component Libraries module is installed and enabled.

#### custom_theme.Libraries.yml

```
scripts:
  # If this library had JavaScript you could specify it like this:
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery

global-scripts:
  version: 1.x
  js: 
    js/script.js: {}
```

#### custom_theme.info.yml

```
    libraries:
  - custom_theme/base
  # @TODO Remove these libraries and use attach_library() for all component styles.
  - custom_theme/scripts
  - custom_theme/global-scripts
  - custom_theme/box
  - custom_theme/comment
  - custom_theme/header
  - custom_theme/hidden
  - custom_theme/inline-links
  - custom_theme/inline-sibling
  - custom_theme/print-none
  - custom_theme/responsive-video
  - custom_theme/wireframe
  - custom_theme/autocomplete
  - custom_theme/collapsible-fieldset
  - custom_theme/form-item
  - custom_theme/form-table
  - custom_theme/progress-bar
  - custom_theme/progress-throbber
  - custom_theme/resizable-textarea
  - custom_theme/table-drag
  - custom_theme/nav-menu
  - custom_theme/navbar
  - custom_theme/pager
```

#### script.js

```
/**
 * @file
 * A JavaScript file for the theme.
 *
 * In order for this JavaScript to be loaded on pages, see the instructions in
 * the README.txt next to this file.
 */

(function (Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      console.log("Hello World");

    }
  };
})(Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The script.js started working after I *cleared all caches*.

If you're having this problem and followed Drupal's official [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme) then login to your Drupal site as admin and In Performance section click **clear all caches**

navigate to: Home >> Administration >> Configuration >> Development